# not install Node.js on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation

Install Node.js:

cd ~

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.18.2 -o nodesource_setup.sh

sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh

after answer -
nodesource_setup.sh: line1: syntaxis error near unexpected token newline

nodesource_setup.sh: line1:

i use tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04 options 2

delete '<>' from '' -> 'DOCTYPE html'
answer: no such command

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Take a look on the nodesource repo: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debian-and-ubuntu-based-distributions

Answer (score 0):

I install node.js v18.18.2 on ubuntu 22.04 for 5 minutes:

Commands:

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash

source ~/.bashrc

nvm install v18.18.2

nvm install lts/hydrogen
```

Comment: The first step is not needed, since you dont do anything with the file/content.